# Launch function when form gets focus without modifying form

Tags: c#, winforms

For all the forms in an application, I need to track when they gain and lose focus.

I tried using the `Form.GotFocus` and `Form.LostFocus` but these events are meant to be used for specific controls like text boxes and thus don't work when a nested control is focused.

Then I tried subscribing to the `GotFucus` of all the `Form.Controls` but this is not reliable as it only works for some sub controls.

Note: Modifying the forms is not an option.

Comment: Either write an [IMessageFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) to capture WM_SETFOCUS messages or if you just need to track the focused Form to a certain degree regularly checking Form.ActiveForm might work. Also [Form.Activated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.activated?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) might help.

Answer (score 0):

When you say keep track, do you mean that you want functions to be performed specifically when focus between forms has changed?

If so, why not try using this:

```
myForm.TopLevel = true // or false
```

Setting this to true for a form will force focus on it during which time you can perform your desired functions and then you can set it to false again, or set it to true for a different form.

This does mean, however, that you will need to display forms in such a way that the “TopLevel” is not obstructing the one behind.